# Managing appearance of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm using the normal scheme for capturing a photo - a UIView subclass with  `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as its layer for showing the preview.
Once the user takes a photo, the preview view needs to be removed but still available in case the user would like to take another photo.

The question is what would be the best approach for optimizing the hide/show of the preview view while keeping to minimum the related setup&configuration steps.
Is switching the preview view's `hidden` property a good idea? Should I also stop the session run when the preview view is hidden? etc.

Comment: I think the best is if you captured a photo, stop session, and hide preview layer. If you want to take another photo, just call session startRunning and show preview layer.

Comment: well the drawback is that startRunning takes too much time so it delays the appearance of the preview view..